# How to resolve Cannot use object of type stdClass as array error in php

Tags: php, arrays

Hello friends here is my code

```
foreach ($pageList as $page) {
    echo var_dump($page);
}
```

this is my output using var_dump

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#41 (2) { ["access_token"]=> string(182) "long string goes here" ["id"]=> string(15) "849929535061042" } }
```

I want to get access token and id in the form of variable like `$page['access_token']=$pageaccesstoken;`. How can i do that from that output.

Comment: `$page->access_token` and `$page->id` ?

Comment: it gives me error Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use like that

```
                  `foreach ($pageList as $page) {
                       $arr = json_encode($page,true);
         $arr1 = json_decode($arr,true);
              //print_r($arr1);

              $pageaccesstoken=@$arr1[0]['access_token'];
  $id=@$arr1[0]['id'];`
```

to access page id and access token.

Answer (score 0):

@CollinD was almost correct, you do need to use an "arrow operator", but you should do that on the 0th element of the array.

Let's look at your var_dump output:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#41 (2) { ... } }
```

What this means is that your `$page` is actually an array of size one, and the 0th element is the object of `stdClass`, and it is that class that has two fields.

The fields are named `access_token` and `id`. In order to access `access_token` you would write:

```
$page[0]->access_token;
```

Comment: if i use $page[0]->access_token the output is Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array .what i do

Comment: @willyadams Could you please double check: 1) that you have copied the for loop correctly into this question 2) that you have copied the result of var_dump into this question correctly. The reason for my request is that the only way that you can get this error is if your `$page` actually isn't an array, and your question clearly shows that it is one.

Comment: sir i am right when i echo $page[0]->access_token  it gives me error            Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in what i do.

Comment: @willyadams Could you please check 1) In in your question your loop is exactly as you have posted. 2) In your question the output of your loop is exactly as you have posted. The only reason to get "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" error is that it is not an array, and your output shows that it is an array.